# Com.pandora.android

Tags: samsung, pandora

I have a photo that started showing up on my camera roll it is in its own file titled com.pandora.android. When I delete it and restart my phone is comes back. The path is /storage/emulated/0/bmwgroup/com.pandora.amdroid.
Does anyone know what it is or how to remove it permanently? This is on a Samsung galaxy 6.

Answer (score 1):

The folder belongs to the [Pandora app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandora.android). You probably don't want to remove it as it will be needed for the app to function.

You can always remove the app and then delete the folder if you dislike it.

Alternatively, you could ensure that your photos app doesn't show photos from that folder (/storage/emulated/0/bmwgroup/com.pandora.android) if that's a supported feature.

Finally, you could create a file titled '.nomedia' in the folder. Then restart your device and the photos application should ignore the photos in the Pandora folder.